# Has "ideological payment" or "emotional payment" qualified someone as a mercenary in a Western or international court of law?

Tags: international, laws-of-war, mercenary

According to a certain [rendition](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/73681/18373) of the Russian viewpoints:

> The persons were motivated entirely by private gain, in this case the "feel-good" emotion that comes with killing Russians [...]

So, while "killing Russians" may not be exactly a high-minded reason to take up arms, have Western or international courts of law ever held that this kind of "ideological/emotional payment" qualifies someone as a mercenary?

Comment: No one from the [Wagner Group - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner_Group) have been charged by an international court of law, despite their involvement, as mercenaries in the civil wars in Syria, Libya, the Central African Republic (CAR), Mali and Ukraine in 2014 and 2022.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If your motivation isn’t material, you aren’t a mercenary

Under the [International Convention against the Recruitment, Use, Financing and Training of Mercenaries](https://casebook.icrc.org/case-study/issue-mercenaries), 4 December 1989:

> A mercenary is any person who:
>
> a  Is specially recruited locally or abroad in order to fight in an armed conflict;
>
> **b**  **Is motivated to take part in the hostilities essentially by the desire for private gain and, in fact, is promised, by or on behalf of a party to the conflict, material compensation substantially in excess of that promised or paid to combatants of similar rank and functions in the armed forces of that party;**
>
> c  Is neither a national of a party to the conflict nor a resident of territory controlled by a party to the conflict;
>
> d  Is not a member of the armed forces of a party to the conflict; and
>
> e  Has not been sent by a State which is not a party to the conflict on official duty as a member of its armed forces.

Furthermore, if these people were serving *in* the Ukrainian military, even In dedicated foreign units, they aren’t mercenaries.